# Magento/jQuery - Get input value AFTER user clicks

Tags: jquery, magento, jgrowl

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and jQuery 1.9.1 with jGrowl. What im trying to achieve is to get the quantity value of the user, and then displaying it as a jGrowl notification on the top right. jGrowl is just a way of displaying text using $.jGrowl("My Text Here"); Heres what I got so far:

HTML

```
    <div class="add-to-cart bottom">

    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="500" title="Qty" onclick="$.jGrowl('500 Added To Cart');" class="input-text qty">
            <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Continue to cart</span></span></button>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
    $('input#qty.input-text.qty').bind("keydown change", function(event){
    $.jGrowl(this.value);
});
```

It works but I the notifcation displays 3 different notifactions are the user types, if I type in 500 in the quantity box, it shows 5, 50, then 500 in seperate notifcations, is there a way to have it display AFTER the user click off the input field?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you don't need `change` if you are using `keydown` in bind.

Comment: tried it, this time it doesnt display anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll provide 2 versions. You should bind your Javascript to an *onclick* or *blur* event instead of keydown:

HTML:

```
<div class="add-to-cart bottom">
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="500" title="Qty" class="input-text qty">
    <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Continue to cart</span></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

jQuery (when user focuses out from input box):

```
jQuery('.add-to-cart.bottom .input-text').blur(function(){
    jQuery.jGrowl(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

**OR**

jQuery (when user clicks button):

```
jQuery('.add-to-cart.bottom .btn-cart').click(function(){
    jQuery.jGrowl(jQuery('.add-to-cart.bottom .qty').val());
});
```

Note it is best practice to avoid the usage of $ for jQuery in Magento due to Prototype & jQuery conflicts. Make sure you're running jQuery in [`noConflict()` mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) too.

Comment: That worked awesomely(lol). You literally just saved me from having a bald head.. ripping out my hairs nonstop on this!

Comment: @Gerardo haha glad to have helped